# Почему неверно работает сво-во padding?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, frontend

Есть вот такой фрагмент макета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь реализовать шапку; собственно, код:

```css
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

.contant_wrapper {
    margin: 0px 141px 0 143px;
}

.header_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 57px;
}

.hat {
    padding: 24px 26px 21px 0px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}

.logo_picture {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #5094f2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.logo_picture span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 4.01875rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.64px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 4px;
}

.logo_text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.logo_text span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2.544rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.42px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 0.761;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 13px;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.margin_right {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 1.26875;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.7;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
}

.face {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prechu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header_wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="contant_wrapper">
                <section class="hat" aria-label="Шапка">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <div class="logo_picture"><span>“</span></div>
                        <div class="logo_text"><span>Prechu</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="margin_right"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="margin_right"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                            <li class="margin_right"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="face">
                <div class="contant_wrapper">contant</div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

    <main>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

И в шапке почему-то не реализовывается заданный padding в классе hat:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при наведении на этот класс в инструментах разработчика выдаёт это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контент блока почему-то выпадает за padding. Почему так происходит?

Проблему я решил тем, что классу добавил фиксированную высоту шапки, которая была в макете, но я с таким сталкиваюсь впервые, хоть и новичок; до этого при реализации блоков у меня получалось реализовывать высоту блока с помощью контента и падингов, без задавания св-ва height вручную.

Я понимаю, что к моему коду и по другим вопросам можно придраться, но просьба обратить внимание именно на эти паддинги. Есть ли возможность реализовать их здесь так, чтобы не задавать вручную высоту "шапки"?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: потому что его содержимое `float`

Comment: Даже если я починил поток свойством clear:both?

Comment: ты не в то место добавил `clear`

Comment: Спасибо!) А где нужно добавить?

Comment: Предполагаю, после nav?

Comment: да, после `nav`, внутри самой секции. Либо изменить на `.clearfix::after` и поставить класс на самом `section`

Comment: Большое спасибо!)